# Change node level without invoking nvm

Tags: nodejs

Looking to switch to a different node release without using nvm as I am struggling to use nvm right now.  I am updating angular from 14 to 16 on ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.  After the update from 14 to 15, I installed node 18.16.1 ... but that seems to have been an issue since Angular was still at 15.  I did nvm use 18.16.1 and did nvm alias default 18.16.1. This was an issue as I believe I needed to wait until Angular was at 16 before that update.  Anyway, now my term won't come up at all and I cannot execute nvm.  I removed .bashrc and can get my terminal up ... but am not able to use nvm.  Hoping there is a config file where I can tell nvm to point to the node 16 that I have installed instead of 18.16.1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I misunderstood the problem.  nvm was not the problem with the term coming up, it was the angular autoComplete that followed.  When using node 18, the final line in .bashrc:

```
    source <(ng completion script)
```

This apparently never returned and hence my term never showed a prompt.  When I commented out that line, my term comes up but I do get the error:

```
    The specified command ("completion") is invalid. For a list of available options, run "ng help".
```

So I believe I'm moving forward and will worry about that particular angular line afterwards.